# What's the best way to add a dockedItem directly below my form fields?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

The key word in the title is **directly**. I don't want my docked item to appear at the bottom of the form panel, so there is space between my fields and my docked item. I want the extra space to come below my dockedItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that I was trying to use the wrong tool for the right job. Basically if I'm docking something it should float to the edge of the container to which it is docked. This is part of the concept of docking. What I want is that my buttons should not float like that. Hence I should not dock my buttons.

So, the solution is to add the buttons to the form itself rather than dock them.

Answer (score 0):

try adding toolbar in form items

```
var frm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    width: 350,
    items : [{
        xtype : 'textfield',
        fieldLabel:'textfld1'
    },{
        xtype:'toolbar',
        items: [{
            text : 'btn1'
        },{
            text : 'btn2'
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: That only works when the form is the same height as its content. The point of the question is that my form is larger than the content. When that is the case this will yield a form where the empty space comes between the fields and the toolbar. I want the empty space below the toolbar.

Comment: why do you need space at end of form after toolbar ? give fix height to form and set autoscroll true on form

Comment: Because the form is docked in a larger layout which means the form fills the available space. A solution would of course be to wrap the form in a panel which stretches, but let the form be a fixed height. But to me it sounds inelegant, and I was wondering if there was another solution.